# AWS S3 Delete Multiple Objects error: No value provided for input HTTP label: Key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My function to delete multiple objects:

```
const { S3Client, DeleteObjectCommand } = require('@aws-sdk/client-s3');

exports.deleteImageService = async () => {
  const s3 = new S3Client({
    credentials: {
      accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_PUBLIC_KEY,
      secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_PRIVATE_KEY,
    },
    region: 'ap-southeast-1',
  });
  const command = new DeleteObjectCommand({
    Bucket: 'event-images',
    Delete: {
      Objects: [
        {
          Key: 'events/test2.png',
        },
      ],
    },
  });

  await s3.send(command);

  return {
    status: 200,
  };
};
```

This function return error: `Error: No value provided for input HTTP label: Key.`

Comment: It's plural `DeleteObjectsCommand`, not singular `DeleteObjectCommand`. Use the former to delete multiple objects; use the latter to delete a single object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete a single object, use [DeleteObjectCommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/client/s3/command/DeleteObjectCommand/) (note: singular spelling). Example:

```
const input = {
  "Bucket": "ExampleBucket",
  "Key": "HappyFace.jpg"
};

const command = new DeleteObjectCommand(input);
await client.send(command);
```

To delete a batch of objects, use [DeleteObjectsCommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/client/s3/command/DeleteObjectsCommand/) (note: plural spelling). Example:

```
const input = {
  "Bucket": "examplebucket",
  "Delete": {
    "Objects": [
      {
        "Key": "HappyFace.jpg",
        "VersionId": "2LWg7lQLnY41.maGB5Z6SWW.dcq0vx7b"
      },
      {
        "Key": "HappyFace.jpg",
        "VersionId": "yoz3HB.ZhCS_tKVEmIOr7qYyyAaZSKVd"
      }
    ],
    "Quiet": false
  }
};

const command = new DeleteObjectsCommand(input);
const response = await client.send(command);
```

Comment: Thanks. My bad, I didn't see `s` character